# HTML to image/pdf converter with multi-byte character encoding support

Tags: php, html, linux, image, pdf

I am in development of a web application which needs to produce pdf output of html content. I tried using `DOMPDF` library which have excellent css support and it supports unicode characters to some extend. But it does not work with languages like Chinese,Japanese, Arabic etc.

I am not confident of `TCPDF` Library also. Is there any library/binary that support my requirements.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try : http://html2pdf.fr/en ?
It worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

It's an open-source PHP library for generating PDF documents. It's fairly well known, and I've recommended it quite a lot for people wanting to generate PDF from a PHP program.

Typically it's used for generating the PDF from scratch (ie fresh latout, not based on HTML code), but it definitely supports UTF-8, and if you look at the specs you'll see that it has (to quote) "methods to publish some XHTML + CSS code, Javascript and Forms". I haven't used that feature, but it sounds like it would do what you need.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `DOMPDF`  works well for me english and language with accents. THe problem is in Chinese and other languages. I will be happy if there is any workaround with this library.

Answer (score 0):

i have used [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) for a long time reasonably well documented and lots of contributed solution means you can usually solve any problem. Also does not require any libraries. Not though like DOMPDF building from the Dom etc.